# laravel one controller for differents models with same schema

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I am developing an application with a Laravel api server and a C# Winforms frontend. The application has many database models, but most of them consist only in an id field and a name field. No more operations than storing and retrieving that data is needed. The data can't be combined into one table (technically is possible, but it would be a mess) because is totally different data,from postal codes and associated city to families of products.

So I thought, as in C# I could make a generic form, if there is possible to make this in Laravel as it will speed up my work too much.

Edit: Here I attach one example controller I want to make it Generic.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\LocalidadRequest;
use App\Localidad;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LocalidadsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(array("data" => Localidad::all(), "error" => 0), 200);
    }

    public function show(Localidad $localidad)
    {
        return $localidad;
    }

    public function store(LocalidadRequest $request)
    {

        $localidad = Localidad::create($request->all());

        return response()->json($localidad, 201);
    }

    public function update(LocalidadRequest $request, Localidad $localidad)
    {
        $localidad->update($request->all());
        return response()->json($localidad, 201);
    }

    public function delete(Localidad $localidad)
    {
        $localidad->delete();
        return response()->json(null, 204);
    }
}
```

I would like to generalize this controller like this (this isn't real code):

```
public function index()
{
    return response()->json(array("data" => ??::all(), "error" => 0), 200);
}

public function show(Model $routeModel)
{
    return $routeModel;
}

public function store(CommonRequest $request)
{

    $routeModel = ??::create($request->all());

    return response()->json($routeModel, 201);
}

public function update(CommonRequest $request, Model $routeModel)
{
    $routeModel->update($request->all());
    return response()->json($localidad, 201);
}

public function delete(Model $routeModel)
{
    $routeModel->delete();
    return response()->json(null, 204);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? It isn't anything wrong with using several models in the same controller and the controller don't care which tables the models are mapped to. I am also curious why you are using Laravel and not Lumen when you only use it as an API server

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I didn't found that Lumen included Eloquent, which is the feature why I am using Laravel. About multiple models, how can I do that?. I haven found anything about it in laravel documentation

Comment: Laravel do not enforce any 1 to 1 between models and controllers. So in your controller you can use ´$codes = PostalCode::all()´ and ´$cities = City::all()´ or any other model you would like to use in the same controller. You can include what you have tried in your controller already if i have misunderstood the question

Comment: Yes I knew that, but that is not what I want. For example, Imagine I have a controller called CommonController with index, store, update and delete routes. So that I want for the cities map POST /cities/{$city} and POST /postcodes/{$postcode} to CommonController@store and then the controller infer which model is assigned to the route. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the routes I posted there, the correct routes are POST /cities and POST /postcodes/

Comment: Ah, now I think I understand what you are asking about. It is probably possible to do by injecting an empty model to the route. Not really sure how, and I would probably used different functions in the controller for the different models to make the code more readable instead of more clever

Comment: Yes I also thought on that, but that's the same defining various controllers, which I don't want and I neither find it correct due to code repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and can structure the route and controller as follows:

Define a generic controller:

```
abstract class CommonController extends Controller
{
    abstract protected function getModel();

    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(array("data" => ($this->getModel())::all(), "error" => 0), 200);
    }

    ....
}
```

For example, if you have city model, then you can define a city controller and inherit the generic controller:

```
class CityController extends CommonController
{
    protected function getModel()
    {
        return App\City::class;
    }
}
```

For route, register it to corresponding controller:

```
Route::get('cities', 'CityController@index');
....
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks